# How to avoid storing 1 million element in an array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, memory, optimization, tls1.2

I'm parsing a 1 000 000 line csv file in PHP to recover this datas: IP Address, DNS , Cipher suites used. 
In order to know if some DNS (having several mail servers) has different Cipher suites used on their servers, I have to store in a array a object containing the DNS name, a list of the IP Address of his servers, and a list of cipher suites he uses. At the end I have an array of 1 000 000 elements. To know the number of DNS having different cipher suites config on their servers I do:

```
foreach($this->allDNS as $dnsObject){
$res=0;  
  if(count($dnsObject->getCiphers()) > 1){ //if it has several different config
    res++;
  }
return $res;
}
```

Problem: Consumes too much memory, i can't run my code on 1000000 line csv (if I don't store these data in a array, I parse this csv file in 20 sec...). Is there a way to bypass this problem ?

NB: I already put

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```

but this line just bypass the memory error.

Comment: Use a database.

Comment: It will definitely consume memory because you are storing hole csv data in memory. Why don't you import csv into database (maybe in temporary tables) and run queries over that data?

Answer (score 1):

Saving all of those CSV data will definitely take its toll on the memory.

One logical solution to your problem is to have a database that will store all of those data.

You may refer to this [link](http://www.legend.ws/blog/tips-tricks/csv-php-mysql-import/) for a tutorial on parsing your CSV file and storing it to database.

Comment: OK this will solve my memory porblem, but how can I handle the compute time problem ?

Comment: @Arthur, may I ask on how do you "compute" the data?

Comment: I solved my problem using an index array. Indeed before storing the DNS object I checked if it was already in the array. When we are at the end of the csv file, the array containg more thab 500 000 DNS object, and foreach new line read, I had the check all the array to know if it contains already this DNS. Now,  I make an associative array to store the DNS as a key and the index of it in the other array as the value. For example : $mytab['toto.com'] = 9; Thanks to that, I can modify the other array by going directly to the right element, without completely browsing the table.

Answer (score 0):

Write the processed Data (for each Line seperately) into one File (or Database)

```
file_put_contents('data.txt', $parsingresult, FILE_APPEND);
```

FILE_APPEND will append the $parsingresult at the End of the File-Content.

Then you can access the processed Data by file_get_contents() or file().

Anyways. I think, using a Database and some Pre-Processing would be the best Solution if this is needed more often.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) to read and parse the CSV file one line at a time. Keep the data you need and discard the line:

```
// Store the useful data here
$data = array();
// Open the CSV file
$fh = fopen('data.csv', 'r');
// The first line probably contains the column names
$header = fgetcsv($fh);
// Read and parse one data line at a time
while ($row = fgetcsv($fh)) {
    // Get the desired columns from $row
    // Use $header if the order or number of columns is not known in advance
    // Store the gathered info into $data
}
// Close the CSV file
fclose($fh);
```

This way it uses the minimum amount of memory needed to parse the CSV file.